# Dictionary comprehension to compare two dictionaries

Tags: python

How can one compare two different dictionaries using **dictionary comprehension**, in similar fashion as list comprehension. For example, given:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 4}

#create another dict which contains key-(value1 x value2)
dict3 = {'a': 3, 'b': 20, 'c': 12}
```

Comment: ...by writing a dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an intersection of the keys, then access the value in both dictionaries:

```
{k: dict1[k] * dict2[k] for k in dict1.viewkeys() & dict2}
```

This uses [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) which act as sets (and `&` creates a set intersection).

In Python 3 you get dicitonary views via the default methods:

```
{k: dict1[k] * dict2[k] for k in dict1.keys() & dict2}
```

By using the key set intersection, you ensure you only get keys that appear in both dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 4}
>>> { k: v * dict2[k] for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2 }
{'a': 3, 'b': 20, 'c': 12}
```

This includes a check that only those items will be multiplicated which keys exist in both dictionaries. And alternatively, you can swap `dict1` and `dict2` for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all keys are shared:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b':  2, 'c': 3}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 4}
>>> {k: dict1[k] * dict2[k] for k in dict1}
{'a': 3, 'c': 12, 'b': 20}
```

If the keys aren't shared:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b':  2, 'c': 3}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'd': 4} # no 'c' key
>>> {k: dict1[k] * dict2[k] for k in dict1 if k in dict2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 20}
```